# jQuery. Output only unique elements on other array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

There is such an array:

```
arr= [{"name":"Vasya","class_id":"1","class":{"id":"1","class":"1"}},
{"name":"John","class_id":"1","class":{"id":"1","class":"1"}},
{"name":"Smith","class_id":"2","class":{"id":"2","class":"2"}}];
```

Can you please tell how to bring in a separate array of unique values of **class**?

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to return the unique values of some property of the class-object, or just the unique class-objects completely?

The following code will do the latter, but only returns the class objects if all of the properties have unique values (or if the object has different properties):

```
var arrOfUniqueClassObjects = arr.reduce(function (newArr, obj) {
    var isInArr = newArr.some(function (inArr) {
        return Object.keys(inArr).some(function (key) {
            return obj.class.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj.class[key] === inArr[key];
        });
    });
    if (!isInArr) newArr.push(obj.class);
    return newArr;
}, []);
```